# Django decorator to skip fixtures in tests

Tags: django, django-testing, django-fixtures

Is there a decorator in Django that would allow to run the test function without applying fixtures?
Something like:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestSomething(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['test_fixture.json']

    def test_with_fixture(self):
        # test something with fixtures 

    @do_not_use_fixtures
    def test_without_fixtures(self): 
        # test something without fixtures
```

Comment: Perhaps `test_without_fixtures` belongs in a different test case.

Comment: semantically no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's `TestCase` loads the fixtures once for the class [for performance reasons](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading). Therefore it isn't possible to run a test method without fixtures.

It might be possible with `TransactionTestCase`, but you'd have to dive into the Django internals to do this, so I wouldn't recommend it.